# Windows 7-File Copy Issue

Tags: files

I am using Windows 7 and my application server is Windows Xp.
When I copy files from my local to server,it takes long time.
Is there any solution for solving this ?
When I copy files from Xp to Xp, it is fast.

I found a soln in .net
http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/slow-network-file-copy-issues-in-windows-7-caused-by-remote-differential-compression/

I tried it ,but no change

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest trying the richcopy program to speed things up a little as it uses multiple threads to copy files?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blo

Comment: I would suggest TeraCopy as another option.

Comment: ok,Thanks.Tried Rich Copy .I can copy a full directory or folder.But couldn't able to upload a single file to a folder